# How to fix PIL Image._show() that shown 'Access Denied' in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i have a problem when trying to showing new bitmap image from my code.
here is the code :

```
from PIL import Image
import pydicom as dicom

dataset = dicom.read_file('D:\File Python\DICOM\Z93')

rows = dataset.Rows
columns = dataset.Columns
img = Image.new('L', (rows, columns))

# inserting data to img from DICOM data
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        img.putpixel([i, j], int(dataset.pixel_array[i, j])) 

Image._show(img)
```

normally, the last line of code must be showing the new image from img. but it shown a message :

```
Access is denied.
```

is anybody here can solve this problem?, it would be really helpfull

Comment: Do you have a file named Z93? Or is this a directory? If you are trying to open a specific file use 'D:\File Python\DICOM\Z93\Myfile.dcm" But if you are using read_file to open and entire directory that is not an option.

Comment: sure i have, the file does'nt have .dcm format. and if i print data with `print(dataset.pixel_array)` or `print(dataset)`, it works. the last line of that code is the only problem

Comment: Try importing "from PIL import ImageShow" then use "ImageShow.show()" Per commenting in PIL's source files Image._show() called ImageShow directly. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageShow.html#module-PIL.ImageShow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this is a permissions issue.
Try looking at the file permissions; The file will need read permissions.